# Location of Third Party Dll's in Version Control for .NET Project

Tags: .net, version-control

What would be the ideal location (directory) to check in Third Party Reference Dll's for a .NET Project in a version control system. Typically i have seen most people to put them under bin, so that the runtime can automatically pickup these files. However is that the right way to go.

I originally wanted to have a separate directory which is parallel to bin called lib which will contain all third party Dll's , but this needs changes to the applications config file so that the lib directory is picked up by the run time. My idea over here is that lib will contain third party dll's while bin will contain the projects Binary (could be Dll or Exe)

What is the preferred way, The concentration over is the location in the Version Control and not just the Physical File System.

Comment: Why is this a concern?

"I originally wanted to have a seperate directory which is parallel to bin called lib which will contain all third party Dll's , but this needs changes to the applications config file so that the lib directory is picked up by the run time"

Comment: well it seems not everyone knows that you can do a runtime binding to directories, and since my final aim is to make the team use it, it kind of feels complex for them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We use the following directory structure (more details available [on my blog](http://code.logos.com/blog/2012/11/building-code-at-logos-repository-layout.html)):

```
Solution\
  Libraries\
    third-party DLLs here
  Source\
    Project1\
    Project2\
```

Each project references (using the "Browse" tab in the Add Reference dialog) the assemblies in the "Libraries" folder. These are automatically copied to each project's "bin" folder at compile time. (The "Libraries" folder is, of course, committed to version control.)

Comment: One reason i wanted to have a seperate lib dir, is that i dont like the way VS copies over dll's to bin dir, so i wanted the reference path and thr runtime path of the dll to be the same relative path. FYI, this is how we already have as of now at solution level.

Comment: What if there are DLLs from other projects within the company or open-source for which you generate 3rd party DLL from code ? That project publishes its DLL. So does that project commit its own DLL every time its code changes ?

Comment: @Munish Goyal: It depends. If the code is changing frequently and is easy for all developers on the team to build, we usually commit its source to version control, and have it build as part of the solution. If the code changes infrequently, is difficult or takes a long time to build (e.g., is C++ but all other projects are C#) then we appoint one developer to be the maintainer of that 3rd-party project and to commit updated DLLs whenever there's a significant change; all other developers just reference the prebuilt DLLs. The workflow really depends on what making that project easy to consume.

Comment: I think last line is well-said. Depends on ease of consumption. Say i have 10 utility libraries (file, string, html etc etc) which are used by multiple bigger business projects in the company. Now every team wouldnt want to include project reference (code) to these util libs. But then versioning presents a difficulty. Because the utils project and business projects would be in different code-lines. How to manage that ? [PS: I realize i may not have presented the situation fully clear here]

Answer (score 9):

Have the separate directory contain the third-party assemblies (this will make things easier to maintain in source control) and then create references in your project to those assemblies.  Then, on build, your third-party assemblies will be copied into your `\bin` and you won't have to make any configuration changes.

Comment: Yeah, this is the method I almost always see. A "Libraries" directory under the root directory from which you reference all DLLs in your project is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I assume those 3rd party DLLs would be used in more that one project of yours. Therefore putting the DLL directly under bin of every project means you end-up having as many DLL copies (in the VCS) as there are projects, which is not elegant. As Andrew H. mentionned, if the DLLs are truly common, they should be put in a common directory that will be refered to by all other projects that need it. 
The only catch here is being able to distinguish different versions of the same DLL: over time, you may end up with something like:

```
/common/ThirdPartyLibrary.dll  (version 1.2)    
/common/ThirdPartyLibrary.dll  (version 1.3)
```

The best way I know (for now) around that is renaming the 3rd party DLL with an explicit version number and refer to that new name in your project, such that your project will always, for sure, refer to the right version. Like:

```
/common/ThirdPartyLibrary_v1.2.dll    
/common/ThirdPartyLibrary_v1.3.dll
```