# Where to place Dlls in version control visual studio

Tags: c#, version-control, version

My Current structure is as follows

- /Project Name/
- file1.cs
- file2.cs
- project.sln
- Libraries/

I know the common answer is to put a Libraries folder within the /Project Name/ folder as shown above. Is this correct?

If so, do I need to do anything special when adding the references in my project? What do I need to set for the "Copy Local" option? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For an answer to the first question, see [Location of Third Party Dll's in Version Control for .NET Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/763309/location-of-third-party-dlls-in-version-control-for-net-project/).

For your second question: nothing special needs to be done; adding a Reference in Visual Studio (using the Browse tab) will automatically set up the assembly DLL to be copied to the output folder.